# static_assert triggering during function name resolution

Tags: c++11, overloading, static-assert

The following code will static_assert when calling the member function A::Get with a string literal, presumably because the function overloading naming resolution must instantiate the template regardless of whether it is selected.

```
template<typename T>
struct helper
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Must be integeral type");

    typedef T type;
};

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {}

    std::string Get(const char* value) const
    {
        return std::string(value) + " (non-template)";
    }

    template<typename T>
    typename helper<T>::type Get(T value) const
    {
        return value;
    }
};
```

I can stop the assert by adding a 'helper' specialization, however there are other situations where the helper class is used, and it doesn't make sense to specialize for 'const char*' in other situations.

Is there some way to stop the helper::type from being instantiated with 'const char*' in this case? If not, what is a better way to design the helper class to avoid this problem?

Comment: You can check [std::enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to stop the templated `Get` method from be instantiated with `const char*` you could use [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if). That way you could disable the function when `T` is of type `const char*`. Here is an implementation of your `Get` method using `std::enable_if`:

```
template<typename T>
typename helper<typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<const char*, T>::value>::type>::type Get(T value) const
{
    return value;
}
```

It is pretty long, but it avoids having to specialize `helper<T>` for the `const char*` case. It works by removing the method from overload resolution when `T` is `const char*`.

You can see the documentation for `std::is_same` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same). Both types are in the [`<type_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) header.